# Embedded Payment : How to get pay key to process preapproval

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

According to Paypal Adaptive Payment :

For Preapproval request we need a endpoint call (1 , mentioned below) , works ok, but not mobile friendly

End Point
1) https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey=value
needed to preapproval request.

End Point (Embed Payment)
2) https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=value&preapprovalkey=value

This case needed paykey , which is required , but preapproval request dont need paykey , How could i call this  2) end point with just preapproval key Like endpoint 1)

Thanks in Advanced

Answer (score 0):

You would make a call to the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) to obtain a pay key.

Comment: is paypalsandbox is down , because   https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey=value mal functioning

Comment: Working fine for me.  What problem are you having?  Have you tried clearing browser cache or using a different browser?